# Winforms OnFormClosing and Disposing/Close

Tags: c#, winforms, dispose

I have a form that I want to override the method OnFormClosing. Does this method need to explicitly call Close or Dispose?

Here is my Parent Form

```
public partial class MyParentForm : Form
{

   // Other methods

   public void RunChildForm()
   {
      Hide();

      var child = new MyChildForm()
      {
         Owner = this
      };

      child.Play();
   }

}
```

Here is my Child Form

```
public partial class MyChildForm : Form
{

   // Other methods

   public void Play()
   {
      Show();
   }

   protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
   {

      // WHAT IS THE CORRECT ORDER?
      // Some code
      ...

      // Display the owner form
      Owner.Show(); 

      base.OnFormClosing(e);

      // Here, is the Form Disposed/Closed? I am unsure if this is necessary.
      Close();
      Dispose();
   }
}
```

What should the order of execution be? I want to clean up the child form, and then display the parent again.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do, but have you considered just handling the `FormClosing` event.

Comment: When I click X (Close) on the child form, I want to clean up everything and redisplay the parent form again.

Comment: The Owner is set with  `var child = new MyChildForm(this);`. Not sure why you used `Play()` when you already have `Show()`. Remove `Dispose()` and `Close()` from `OnFormClosing`. If you have disposable objects you created, dispose of those.

Comment: So when closing the form, it will cleanup everything? I have managed my objects, but wondering if the form explicitly needs to be managed when closed?

Comment: By clean up, do you mean Disposal?  If so, override `Dispose(bool)` in the normal fashion

Comment: When X is clicked on the form, are all components cleaned up regarding the child form?

Comment: @Flydog57  `Dispose(bool)` is already overridden, in Form.Designer.cs. One could move it to the Form.cs file, but it's not needed.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't really want to "override the method OnFormClosing".

Based on what you've said, your best bet might be to simply write an event handler for "FormClosing".

In Java-land (at least before Java 8), you commonly created an anonymous class that overrode the method(s) you wanted to customize.

In C#/.Net-land - and particularly with Winforms event handlers - MSVS makes it easy to use [delegates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/)